# How to use jQuery to change css div visibility on checkbox input?

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox, visibility

I'm trying to change the visibility of a div based on a jQuery .click of a checkbox input.

I've been working on fixing an issue with a Full Screen CSS Nav. This is the modified CodePen: http://codepen.io/tedrem/pen/OVbYde

Visibility Toggle:

```
$.fn.toggleVisibility= function() {
var $this  = $(this);
if($this.css("visibility")=="hidden"){
    $this.css("visibility","visible")
}else{
    $this.css("visibility","hidden")
}
return this;
};
```

Checkbox Click to Initiate the Function:

```
$(".checkbox-toggle").click(function (){
   $("#links").toggleVisibility();
})
```

Relevant HTML Lines: 3 & 7
Relevant CSS Lines: 123

NOTE: This is currently not working. The div remains hidden

Comment: Your codepen doesn't include jquery, so it's throwing an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. I added jQuery and it works fine.

Comment: @T3D Could you define more clearly, what you want? I mean you want is that the menu links(About,Products,Blog,Contact) to display on click menu icon?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example (on the link), Just remove Line 123 on your CSS and it will be fine.